# Facing error in mongodump command from jenkins server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, authentication, jenkins, mongodump

i have created a user with

```
db.createUser(
{   user: "abc",
    pwd: "password",

    roles:[{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase" , db:"db_name"}]})
```

now i want to run mongodump command from my jenkins server for which i am using

```
mongodump --host=private_ip_of_mongo_server --port=27017 --authenticationDatabase="db_name" -u="abc" -p="password"
```

but this command is giving me error

Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.

there are no issues with SG as i can login from my jenkins server to mongo server and my VM's are in aws ec2 instance and OS is ubnutu 20, but mongodump command is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the version of mongodump, whether is compatible with the mongo-server....

download the lasted version from

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools

Comment: Unfortunately mongodump was rewritten in golang so now contains go related ssl bugs like: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2598. Any workaround alternative work around might be appreciated